# My Custom Function Runs Successfully With Code, But With Formula Returns #VALUE

Tags: excel, vba, function, macros, formula

I created a function to get a product's property with the given Product-Number.

It works successfully when I run from module, but not from formula.

Function (edited):

```
Public Function ÖZELLİKGETİR(İsim As String, Özellik As String) As String
    Dim Okunan() As Römork
    Okunan() = VERİGETİR()

    Dim i
    MsgBox UBound(VERİGETİR()) '0
    ReDim Preserve Okunan(UBound(VERİGETİR()) + 1)
    MsgBox "Reached" 'Even this is not reached
    For i = 0 To UBound(Okunan())
    If Not Okunan(i) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Reached"
        If Okunan(i).ÜrünKodu = İsim Then
        MsgBox "Reached"
            ÖZELLİKGETİR = CallByName(Okunan(i), Özellik, VbGet)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    Next i

End Function
```

The other parts are really long, and since it works with macro; I did not need to include those.

My Working Macro:

```
Sub T()
    ÖZELLİKGETİR("NM 511.136","ÜrünKodu") 'Returns "NM 511.136"
End Sub
```

Formula:

```
=ÖZELLİKGETİR("NM 511.136";"ÜrünKodu") Returns #VALUE
```

The spreadsheet if you need other parts:
[Link](http://www.filedropper.com/kopyarmorklistesi20161226)

Comment: Start by putting `Option Explicit` at the beginning of all your modules.  This will force you to explicitly declare all variables, and may lead you to your problem.  (And you should set `Tools/References` to require that also).  If that doesn't help, put break points on every line in your UDF to see where it is failing.  The UDF itself is not returning the error; rather it more likely coming from a "bad line" in the code.  One possibility is that `VERİGETİR` does not have a value within the code when your UDF is called from the worksheet.

Comment: OH MY! Variable i is not defined! Thank you dude, I was searching more than 2 hours.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld But... Its still #VALUE

Comment: If you have set `Option Explicit`, then proceed to step two in my comment.

Comment: In Excel a `UDF` (function called as a cell formula) cannot do all things what a normal function can do, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787.

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz  Also, what would `Römork` be in English?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I typed Option Explicit, that pointed me the mistake but, it  still does not reach first MsgBox

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Trailer, I believe.

Comment: @AxelRichter So Excel Can't Run My Function From Formula?

Comment: You have to isolate the line that is failing.  It should be either the `ReDim` line or something before.  If it gets that far, what is the value of `VERİGETİR` when you enter the UDF?  You can put a break point on the `ReDim` line to halt your UDF before it fails.  If

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz I should have asked you for the equivalent DataType in English.  Trailer is not a datatype in English VBA and would cause an error..

Comment: I have a class module for that.

Comment: I used foreach to get values, and its length is 1 and consists of Römork. Also code runs until ReDim with formula, entire code runs with Macro

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I think it would be easier to understand the problem if you are running on it.

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz I tried running it, but I think because of the language issues, I got a `#NAME?` error when trying to run the formula from the worksheet.

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz What is the value of VERİGETİR when your code stops on the `Redim` line?  What is it's `Ubound`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Its 0, but i use UBound + 1

Comment: @RonRosenfeld VERİGETİR() Returns an array that contains only one Römork

Comment: If you are using your Function  as a UDF, shouldn't it return a `String` or something ? like : `Public Function ÖZELLİKGETİR(İsim As String, Özellik As String)  As String` ? or `Variant`

Comment: @ShaiRado Sorry, I forgot to update the code, it returns String.

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz What happens if, when your UDF has stopped at the breakpoint, you execute the line in the immediate window, perhaps in stages:  `?UBound(VERİGETİR()) + 1`  and then the entire line?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It doesn't even break on breakpoint, it just doesn't run.

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz Put a breakpoint on the first line of your code that allows it -- the line that now reads `Okunan() = VERİGETİR()`.  Make sure you have selected the option to `Break on unhandled errors` or `Break on all errors`

Comment: When I try to print something of Römork, It says wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment?

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz Unlikely for that to be the problem with this UDF.  But I cannot get it to run here.  I'll try again later but will be busy today.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131971/discussion-on-question-by-talha-talip-acikgoz-my-custom-function-runs-successful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to take a look inside your workbook to get an idea of what is going wrong. A little bit tough for someone who doesn't speak your language :)

Well, after all, it IS due to what @RonRosenfeld and @AxelRichter pointed out: User-Defined Functions (UDF) have restrictions.

In your VBA code, you count *a lot* on the `ActiveSheet` and you use unqualified ranges. For instance, in your function `VERÝGETÝR` you start it with `Sheets("Veri Sayfasý").Activate`; then you call many functions with unqualified `Cells(r, c)`.

Take a little look here:

```
    In Sub  VERÝGETÝR(...)
        Sheets("Veri Sayfasý").Activate
        ...
        Set vRömork.DingilSayýsý = MetinOluþtur(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, i + 1))
        Set vRömork.Ton = MetinOluþtur(Cells(3, i), Cells(3, i + 1))
        Set vRömork.En = SayýOluþtur(Cells(4, i), Cells(4, i + 1))
        ...
```

All this works with normal VBA, although it is not even recommended. (Professionals should never use the `Activate` stuff unless really necessary, I almost never found a situation where we cannot avoid it). BUT, inside a UDF, the `Activate` method has no effect, it is **totally ignored** !

Solution: refactor your code and qualify all your `Range` and `Cells` stuff. Make sure you *never* use the `ActiveSheet` or the `Activate` stuff. For instance, your above code could be easily rewritten using a `With` clause instead of using `Activate`:

```
       With Sheets("Veri Sayfasý") // <~~ no need to activate, just a With
           Set vRömork.DingilSayýsý = MetinOluþtur(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(2, i + 1))
           Set vRömork.Ton = MetinOluþtur(.Cells(3, i), .Cells(3, i + 1))
           Set vRömork.En = SayýOluþtur(.Cells(4, i), .Cells(4, i + 1))
           ...
       End with
```

It might be a tedious task for the moment but I *Strongly* recommend to refactor your code. I seems to be a pretty big project and you need to stick to good practice rules in order to have it maintainable and to avoid further surprises.